# Powershell named pipe security?

Tags: powershell, named-pipes

How can I set up a Powershell named pipe to be available to all users on the local computer?

I'm writing a small Powershell script and I need to be able to have any user on the local computer be able to write to a named pipe that will be consumed by this script.

I can get the pipe set up with the following:

```
$pipe=new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("\\.\pipe\mypipe")
$pipe.WaitForConnection()  
$sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($pipe)
while (($cmd= $sr.ReadLine()) -ne 'exit') 
....
```

I'm not sure how to use the System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity in conjunction with this.

EDIT: I'm using PS v2 if it matters.

EDIT2:

I've made some progress in getting a named pipe security definition created. Still not sure how to bind it.

```
$PipeSecurity = new-object System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity
$AccessRule = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRule( "Users", "FullControl", "Allow" )
$PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
$pipe=new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("\\.\pipe\mypipe");
$pipe.SetAccessControl( $PipeSecurity )
```

Comment: I think you just need to use the overload in `new-object` that takes in a PipeSecurity object. See [this old SO question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478166/named-pipe-server-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception-when-creating-a-seccond-ins) asking about a similar problem in C#, you may be able to translate it in to PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the right constructor, that property can't be set afterwards.  This will do the trick:

```
$PipeSecurity = new-object System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity
$AccessRule = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRule( "Users", "FullControl", "Allow" )
$PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
$pipe=new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("p","In",100, "Byte", "Asynchronous", 32768, 32768, $PipeSecurity);
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! Note the following line should be included as well before creating the pipe: $PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)