# IPC Between SYSTEM Account and Current User

Tags: c#, wcf, ipc

I need to write a C# program that executes operations requiring elevated privileges, but also has a UI that a limited-rights user can interact with (to initiate the privileged operations and see the results of those operations). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a zillion alternatives.  I'd consider:

1) use a Windows service to handle the "operations requiring elevated privileges",

2) write a small, simple WinForms app for your UI, and

3) Use Windows "named pipes" to communicate between your client and service

Here's a tutorial:

http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Comment: I would re-word #3 slightly *"Use WCF over Windows Named Pipes to communicate between your client and service"*. Using raw Named Pipes to go between privileged and non privileged processes [can be a PITA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478166/named-pipe-server-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception-when-creating-a-seccond-ins). Letting WCF handle the pipe management over a `net.pipe` channel (which is what the tutorial you linked to does) makes it a LOT easier.