# NamedPipeClientStream not work in app service

Tags: c#, azure, pipe

my code work good in my server but in azure app service i get this error "The operation has timed out." in the line`enter code here`

```
 pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut);
```

my code

```
public void Send(string SendStr, string PipeName, int TimeOut = 1000)
    {
        try
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

            // The connect function will indefinitely wait for the pipe to become available
            // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
            pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut);
            Debug.WriteLine("[Client] Pipe connection established");

            byte[] _buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SendStr);
            pipeStream.BeginWrite(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, AsyncSend, pipeStream);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException oEX)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(oEX.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After much work it solved my problem is almost completely
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478552/5996253